# Почему некорректно выводятся cross sells?

Tags: woocommerce

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему некорректного вывода cross sells товаров.
Задача в том, чтобы предлагать в нагрузку к текущему товару ещё несколько других.

Убираю вывод cross sell из корзины и вывожу в карточку товара:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'woocommerce_cross_sell_display' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_cross_sell_display');
```

Создаю два вариативных товара: `a-product` и `b-product`

Товару `a-product` присваиваю кросселлом родительский `b-product`, то есть не вариацию, а основной.
Товару `b-product`, соответственно, присваиваю `a-product` как кросселл.

На выходе жду очевидную картинку, где к `a-product` предлагается в нагрузку `b-product`, и наоборот. А получаю ситуацию, в которой в карточке `a-product` предлагается `b-product` как кросселл, а в карточке `b-product` предлагается кросселл самого себя, то есть `b-product`.

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема может быть связана с тем, что вы устанавливаете кросс-селл для родительского товара, но вариации этого товара не наследуют этот атрибут. Это происходит потому, что по дефолту WooCommerce выводит кросс-селл для вариаций, а не для родительских товаров.

Нужно переопределить функцию woocommerce_cross_sell_display() так, чтобы она использовала кросс-селл родительского товара для вариаций.